# Window won't restore after it is closed

Tags: cocoa

When I fire up my OS X app from Xcode, it appears as it should.

When I close the window, it disappears (as you would expect), and the app still appears active on the dock.

Great, that's how it should be. But when I click the dock to activate the window, it doesn't show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you closing it? quitting the app vs hiding or minimizing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There isn't much information in the question, but let me presume that the app is a single-window app (i.e., not `NSDocument`-based).

A typical situation in this scenario is that the user closes the window, and the appliction keeps running with the icon in the Dock as it is supposed to.

In that situation, the user would normally like the window to re-appear when the app is activated by clicking the icon in the Dock.

To obtain that, you can implement `applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)visibleWindows
{   
    if ( visibleWindows ) {
        [self.window orderFront:self];
    }
    else {
        [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: sorry for the lack of information in the question.. will give this a try and let you know.. cheers

Comment: just the ticket thanks @Monolo - remembering the 'Release when closed' option is unticked in IB else will cause a crash calling 'makeKeyAndOrderFront'

Answer (score 13):

for swift:

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
    if let window = sender.windows.first {
        if flag {
            window.orderFront(nil)
        } else {
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        }
    }

    return true
}
```